# Is it possible to grab the cookie from the view in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I was just wondering if it's possible, I was looking to grab the cookie to see if it's an admin user, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: do you mean in controller?

Comment: I meant, grab the information from a cookie while in the view/from the html file. It is worded a little weird, sorry.

Comment: why do you need to grab it in view instead controller what is your goal here can you tell me your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$cookies` for reading and writing into cookies...

example from angular [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/%24cookies)

```
  function ExampleController($cookies) {
    // Retrieving a cookie
    var favoriteCookie = $cookies.myFavorite;
    // Setting a cookie
    $cookies.myFavorite = 'oatmeal';
  }
```

**UPDATE**

you should add **angular-cookies.js** script and inject `ngCookies` into you application module

```
angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);
```